# Moq object doesn't invoke method

Tags: c#, moq

I got a class which I created a mock for so I can test it.

The class itself looks something like this:

```
public class MyData
{
    private string data;
    private string path;
    
     public MyData(string apath)
     {
        this.path = apath;
     }

    public virtual async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        if(IsDataExpired())
        {
            data = await CreateData();
        }
        return data;
    }

    protected virtual bool IsDataExpired() { ... }
    protected virtual async Task<string> CreateData() { ... }
}
```

And the test:

```
 public void TestData()
    {
        string data = "some data";
        Mock<MyData> dataMock = new Mock<MyData>("path");
               
        dataMock.Protected().Setup<bool>("IsDataExpired").Returns(true);
        dataMock.Protected().Setup<Task<string>>("CreateData").ReturnsAsync(data);
        var dataRes = dataMock.Object.GetData().Result;
        Assert.IsNotNull(dataRes);
    }
```

The problem is that for some reason the `dataRes` is null at the end of the test. I tried debugging inside the class, but it seems like the code doesn't even enter the `GetData` method and doesn't hit any breakpoint, and the dataRes immediately receives a null value.

Am I invoking the method in a wrong way? Why won't it enter the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why won't it enter the method?

Moq will override `virtual` members by default.

Configure the mock to call the base virtual member by setting `CallBase` property to *true*

`CallBase = true` will let the mock invoke base class implementation(s) if no expectation (Setup) overrides the member.

Also since the member under test is asynchronous, the test should also be asynchronous

```
public async Task TestData() {
    //Arrange
    string data = "some data";
    Mock<MyData> dataMock = new Mock<MyData>("path") {
        CallBase = true
    };
           
    dataMock.Protected().Setup<bool>("IsDataExpired").Returns(true);
    dataMock.Protected().Setup<Task<string>>("CreateData").ReturnsAsync(data);

    //Act
    string dataRes = await dataMock.Object.GetData();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(dataRes);
}
```